# How to bind a client to a network socket after the client amount exceeds 65536?

Tags: sockets, networking

I know that for client server communication we need to create sockets  both in  server and client side.So What I am wondering is what would happen when incoming client amount exceeds the number of maximum port number which is 65536  as we know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TCP connections are identified by source and destination IP and port.

Client ports are generally not assigned a local port number before the outbound connection is initiated, at which point the full tuple is known and a conflict-free local port number can be chosen. At least in theory, whether operating systems actually do that is another matter, because there is no real use case for that.

On the server side, all incoming connections use the same local IP and port number, but connections can be distinguished by the client's IP and port number, giving a theoretical limit of 2^32 IP addresses times 2^16 ports, minus a few unusable ones, so about 250 trillion combinations.

For UDP, local ports are bound either explicitly using `bind()` or implicitly when the first packet is sent, in which case a port number must be free -- but UDP is stateless, and packets can be received from all clients at the same time.

In either case, using multiple IP addresses and explicitly binding the socket to an IP will also avoid running into problems, but you wouldn't run into a limitation unless anyone attempts to open more than 2^16 connections between the same two machines.

Comment: ITYM 2^128 + 2^32 IP addresses :-P

Comment: That calculation is with server address fixed, so only client IP and port varies.

Comment: Here as well. There are IP addresses with 32 bits and others with 128 bits.